# How to create a "container" which works like the argparse.ArgumentParser?

Tags: python, class

When writing code most of us will use the Python module `argparse` like below:

```py
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='descript')
parser.add_argument('integers', type=int, help='a number')

opt = parser.parse_args()

train(opt)
```

Then we can pass the `opt` to the function next. And the function can get needed parameters through `opt.integers`.

When doing test in a `.ipynb` file, importing `argparse` and using `add_argument` is too complex. I wonder if there is such a Container works like below:

```py
opt = SpecificContainer()

opt.length = 10
opt.dim = 3
opt.batch = 8

train(opt)
```

That to say, I got `opt` variable. And I can use `opt.val1 = 10` to set the value. And I can pass the `opt` variable to other functions.

Comment: You could use `types.SimpleNamespace`, but it's unclear what do you want.

Comment: You could also use `argparse.Namespace`, which is what argparse actually puts its output in. `SimpleNamespace` is probably more efficient, but the difference would usually not be super relevant I'd expect.

Comment: Thanks, `argparse.Namespace` is what I want!  I have coordinate some solutions to this. Hope it helps for all. @Masklinn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better approach is to not couple all of your code with the `argparse` dependency. Instead, have your function accept a well-defined list of individual arguments, and pick them out from the `argparse` result when you have parsed the command line.

```py
def train(length: int, dim: int, batch: int):
    ...


opt = parser.parse_args()

train(opt.length, opt.dim, opt.batch)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. But doing this is kind of tired when there are many parameters.

Comment: I do agree; it would be nice if `argparse` allowed you to retrieve its members into a list or dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there do exits some ways to realize this. I will do some recording here，just throwing away a brick in order to get a gem.

**Solution 1: argparse.Namespace() (Recommend)**
I consider this is the best way because it is from the `argparse` module. Examples are：

```py
import argparse

opt = argparse.Namespace()
opt.age = 18
opt.name = "Peter"
opt.gender = "male"

print(opt.name)
print(opt)

# The output will be:
#>>> Peter
#>>> Namespace(age=18, gender='male', name='Peter')
```

**Solution 2: types.SimpleNamespace**
Thanks to @NobbyNobbs, I tried `types.SimpleNamespace` and succeded. Examples are:

```py
from types import SimpleNamespace as SN

opt = SN()
opt.age = 18
opt.name = "Peter"
opt.gender = "male"

print(opt.name)
print(opt)

# The output will be:
#>>> Peter
#>>> namespace(age=18, gender='male', name='Peter')
```

You can refer to [types.SimpleNamespace](https://docs.python.org/3/library/types.html#types.SimpleNamespace) for more info.

**Solution 3: `type("options", (), {})()`**
This is a solution provided by my friend, but he did not understand why. A simple example is:

```py
opt = type("options", (), {})()
opt.age = 18
opt.name = "Peter"
opt.gender = "male"

print(opt.name)
print(opt)

# The output will be:
#>>> Peter
#>>> <__main__.options object at 0x7fb0f1b49e50>
```